# Changing the speed of CALayer in CABasicAnimation while rotating a wheel causes jerk effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, calayer, cabasicanimation

I develop an app which requires a wheel to be rotated around z axis with increasing or decreasing the speed of the wheel steadily over time. I use CABasicAnimation & my code is as follows. While i change the speed property of the layer at particular interval, it causes "Jerk" effect to the wheel.

/************/

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-2*M_PI];
animation.duration = 4.0f;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
[animation setValue:@"left" forKey:@"side"];
[animation setDelegate:self];
animation.removedOnCompletion=NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.cumulative = YES;

imageLeft.layer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
/************/
```

In a timer I vary the speed of the CALayer of the imageview as follows where dPlayedPercentage is a variable.

```
imageLeft.layer.speed=1.0+dPlayedPercentage;

[imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
```

I think it is due to the position resets while changing the speed property of CALayer. What should i do to rectify this. Or any other way to do this animation?

Comment: Adding the following code has rectified the jerk in the animation.                imageLeft.layer.timeOffset = [imageLeft.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
 imageLeft.layer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
 imageLeft.layer.speed=1.0+dPlayedPercentage;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding the following code has rectified the jerk in the animation.

```
imageLeft.layer.timeOffset = [imageLeft.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]; 
imageLeft.layer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime(); 
imageLeft.layer.speed=1.0+dPlayedPercentage;
```

Comment: +1 I had pretty much the same problem, of having a layer that was animating, and I wanted to change the speed mid-animation without restarting the animation.  This worked for me, thanks.

Comment: @Augus @Siegfoult I am having similar issue, can you show me how you manage `dPlayedPercentage ` value.

Answer (score 1):

For more dynamic speed change, I has some issue with the previous answer (layer not drawing at all) since the `timeOffset` needed to be calculated with the new speed in mind.

*(source https://coveller.com/2016/05/core_animation_timing)*

The base formula for the `timeOffset` is:
***`timeOffset = CACurrentMediaTime() - ((convertTime - beginTime) x speed)`***

In code:

```swift
theLayer.speed = newSpeed
    
let mediaTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
    
let converedTime = theLayer.convertTime(mediaTime, to: nil)
    
theLayer.beginTime = mediaTime

let offset = mediaTime - ((converedTime - theLayer.beginTime) * Double(newSpeed))

theLayer.timeOffset = offset
```